# How to schedule automatic increment for a column on a particular date

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2014

I have a table with the details of employees, which also enlists how many leaves of each type has an employee availed. The table is scripted as :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee]
(
    [emp_ID] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [username] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [emp_name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [gender] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [password] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [pay_roll_num] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [designation] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [earned_leave] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [halfpay_leave] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,  
    [casual_leave] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,       
    [primary_address] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [primary_phone] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [email_ID] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [manager_ID] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Employee] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([username] ASC)
       WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,        
             ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY] 
TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

I am using Visual studio Ultimate 2013 and SQL Server 2014.

Problem 1:
Now, it is required that on 1st January and 1st July every year, 12 leaves are credited to each employees' account in the earned and half-pay categories. These are carry forwarded.

Eg. If ABC had

```
Earned Leave   = 20
Half-Pay Leave = 10
```

then on midnight as the year changes and 1st january starts, auto increment should happen, resulting in,

```
Earned Leave   = 50
Half-Pay Leave = 40
```

I tried to do this on page_load event on admin side by making a simple function that compared id `datetime.now` returned 01/01 and if yes, then increment. But then I realized, this will happen every time the admin logs in on the 2 aforementioned dates. Any other method or page that I thought of doing this on, required that the application be started while I want this to happen in the backend without any human intervention.

Problem 2:
The admin should be showed a record of the credit and debit of leaves taking place in each user account, like a log. How do I show this in a gridview or table or any way? 
Example, when admin logs in and selects an employee name to view their leave balance-sheet, it should look something like below (with the same type of details for all kinds of leaves)

```
   Employee name: Abc Designation: Xyz Date of joining: 01/01/2008 **Credit Leaves**

                   Earned Leave
   Credit for     Leave Availed      No. of Days 
                  From  To          D      C     Balance
   1/1/12                           12           50
                  7/4   10/4        4            46
   1/7/12                                   12   58
                  13/08  23/08      11           47                       
                  04/09  08/09      05           42
   23/10      Leave Encashment      10           32 
   1/1/13                                   12   34  
   1/7/13                                   12   46
                  22/12  31/12      10           36    
   1/1/14                                   12   48
```

As, the above makeshift table displays, a set number of leaves are to be credited on the specific dates and when leave is encashed.
Now, the admin should be able to add leaves when an employee cashes his leaves,by clicking on the Credit Leaves button (emboldened text). ALSO, yearly log should be displayed and on changing year, that year's log should be displayed.

I have absolutely no idea how to do this kind of log publishing in a gridview. Please help me.

Comment: You might need to use sql server service to do this.

Comment: Your answer is: SQL Agent Jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some options:

1. SQL Agent Jobs - you can run a particular stored procedure at designated date or repeatedly if configured so. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189237.aspx
2. ASP.NET package called "Hangfire" available at [Hangfire.io](http://hangfire.io) - it is well documented and available over NuGET.

There are many others, but these two are quite reliable

Comment: Thank you for the link, I shall certainly try this. But does this also solve the log display problem?